# How to make mysqldump use /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

When I use mysqldump to export mysql database, it always produce a dump.sql containing

```
...some other things...
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8*/;
...some other things...
```

This is the mysqldump command I use:

```
mysqldump -u root -p databaseName -R -E --single-transaction --default-character-set=utf8mb4 > dump.sql
```

The charset of the mysql database is `utf8mb4` rather than `utf8`, the characters related variables is:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci         |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci         |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci         |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Why does *mysqldump* always add 
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8*/` rather than 
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4*/`?

What happens if `/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8*/` is used?

Can we have *mysqldump* use `/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4*/`?

Answer (score 11):

That special type of comment says "leave this as a comment if running a version older than 4.1.1; else execute it".

`utf8mb4` came in in 5.5.3, so the 'correct' version would be

```
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4*/
```

If your version of mysqldump and mysql are newer than 5.5.3, no harm is done by leaving it `40101`.  If you do try to load it on a mysql older than 5.5.3, the `SET` will probably complain.

As for why mysqldump does not say 50503 -- I suspect that is a bug.  File it at http://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: From the MySQL documentation: _if you add a version number after the ! character, the syntax within the comment is executed only if the MySQL version is **greater than** or equal to the specified version number_ meaning the exact opposite of this answers first line is correct.

Comment: Is it a bug? Or perhaps a newer version of mySQL became _more_ backwards compatible? As of 5.7.37, it seems to dump as `40101` and no longer `50503`

Comment: @Trip - Character sets were added in 4.1.1, but `utf8mb4` was not added until 5.5.3.  Does this explain the issues?